# Eliminate repeated code in PHP

Tags: php

I have this piece of code below:

```
<?php
//Dados do Pregão para pegar dados e para o email
$pregao = ($newuasg[2]);
$uasg = ($newuasg[3]);
$url = ("http://www.comprasnet.gov.br/livre/Pregao/mensagens_acomp.asp?prgcod=$nova[1]");
$contents = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

//Verifica a data/hora da mensagem com a data/hora atual
$a=preg_match_all("/\<span class\=\"mensagem2\"\>(.*?)\<\/span\>/",$contents,$b);
$date = ($b[1][0]);
$date = str_replace("(", "", $date);
$date = str_replace(")", "", $date);
$newdate = $date[6] . $date[7] . $date[8] . $date[9] . $date[2] . $date[3] . $date[4] . $date[5] . $date[0] . $date[1] . $date[10] . $date[11] . $date[12] . $date[13] . $date[14] . $date[15] . $date[16] . $date[17] . $date[18];

//Verifica se alguma das palavras chaves foi encontrada
$resultado = procpalavras($contents, $palavras);

//Envia email caso ache qualquer das palavras indicadas
if ($resultado === null) {
echo "Pregão:" . $pregao . " - Uasg" . $uasg . " - Palavras não encontradas";
} else if ($newdate <= $envio) {
} else {
include 'mail.php';
}
?>
```

I repeat this code for the next 1000 lines just changing the number in [] for $pregao, $uasg and $url. Always increasing 1 number in each statement.
Is there a way to make a code that i dont need to repeat this code over and over again?

Comment: Do yuo use that variables only in echo? Why do you repeat all the code?

Comment: put these code in a PHP function with the necessary parameters you have declared and the call them from inside a loop.

Comment: @splash58, just this 3 variables ($pregao, $uasg and $url) have changes in the code only in the numbers in []. It takes too long to read all the lines and do the result (echo or send mail)

Comment: @RatulSharker , i dont know how to do that. Im not a programmer, just make this code to make my work easier.

Comment: @JohnPabloMartins There's no need to add **SOLVED** to your title. Accepting an answer does this for you, and helps other users as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may help you

```
// here is the loop which will iterate over 1000 time
 // feel free to change the 1000 to what you prefer
 for ($x = 0; $x < 100; $x++)
 {
     // acquiring the params
     $pregao = ($newuasg[0+($x*2)]);
     $uasg = ($newuasg[1+($x*2)]);
     $url = ("http://www.comprasnet.gov.br/livre/Pregao/mensagens_acomp.asp?prgcod=" . $nova[0+$x]);

    $contents = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

    //Verifica a data/hora da mensagem com a data/hora atual
    $a=preg_match_all("/\<span class\=\"mensagem2\"\>(.*?)\<\/span\>/",$contents,$b);
    $date = ($b[1][0]);
    $date = str_replace("(", "", $date);
    $date = str_replace(")", "", $date);
    $newdate = $date[6] . $date[7] . $date[8] . $date[9] . $date[2] . $date[3] . $date[4] . $date[5] . $date[0] . $date[1] . $date[10] . $date[11] . $date[12] . $date[13] . $date[14] . $date[15] . $date[16] . $date[17] . $date[18];

    //Verifica se alguma das palavras chaves foi encontrada
    $resultado = procpalavras($contents, $palavras);

    //Envia email caso ache qualquer das palavras indicadas
      if ($resultado === null) {
    echo "Pregão:" . $pregao . " - Uasg" . $uasg . " - Palavras não encontradas";
} else if ($newdate <= $envio) {
} else {
       include 'mail.php';
      }
 }
?>
```

Comment: I modified a bit your code, cause it wasn't sending mail (following the conditions), but now i have a little problem. In the variables $pregao and $uasg, i use another variable $newuasg. The problem is that i use this variable $newuasg 2 times in each statement, so when it make the first one (newuasg[0] and newuasg[1]), the next must be newuasg[2] and newuasg[3], but im getting newuasg[1] and newuasg[2].

Comment: so you want to increment by 2 for $newusag, but increment by 1 for $nova ?

Comment: code updated, check for the `($x*2)` inside the loop.

Comment: Worked. But i had made some changes to your code, to send mail.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
for ($i=0; $i < 1000; $i++) {
    $pregao = ($newuasg[1 + $i]);
    $uasg = ($newuasg[2 + $i]);      
}
```

It will loop through the function from 0 to 1000 ( you can set that value dynamically) adding one to $i every loop, then adding $i to your variables.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php

 // here is the loop which will iterate over 1000 time
 // feel free to change the 1000 to what you prefer
 for ($x = 0; $x < 100; $x++)
 {
     // acquiring the params
     $pregao = ($newuasg[0+($x*2)]);
     $uasg = ($newuasg[1+($x*2)]);
     $url = ("http://www.comprasnet.gov.br/livre/Pregao/mensagens_acomp.asp?prgcod=" . $nova[0+$x]);

    $contents = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

    //Verifica a data/hora da mensagem com a data/hora atual
    $a=preg_match_all("/\<span class\=\"mensagem2\"\>(.*?)\<\/span\>/",$contents,$b);
    $date = ($b[1][0]);
    $date = str_replace("(", "", $date);
    $date = str_replace(")", "", $date);
    $newdate = $date[6] . $date[7] . $date[8] . $date[9] . $date[2] . $date[3] . $date[4] . $date[5] . $date[0] . $date[1] . $date[10] . $date[11] . $date[12] . $date[13] . $date[14] . $date[15] . $date[16] . $date[17] . $date[18];

    //Verifica se alguma das palavras chaves foi encontrada
    $resultado = procpalavras($contents, $palavras);

    //Envia email caso ache qualquer das palavras indicadas
      if ($resultado === null) {
    echo "Pregão:" . $pregao . " - Uasg" . $uasg . " - Palavras não encontradas";
    } else if ($newdate <= $envio) {
    } else {
       include 'mail.php';
      }
 }
?>
```